# Unable to focus on Asp.net TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a TextBox that I am trying to use focus from code behind after a postback. This textbox uses a ListBox with an Ajax DropDownExtender to create a ComboBox. When my page does a PostBack, I call tbEquipType.Focus(), but the box does not come into focus. I believe the issue to be with the Ajax controls, but I am not sure. Any insight? Thanks in advance!

```
<asp:Panel ID="panelEquipType" runat="server" BorderWidth="0">
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbEquipType" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true" />
</asp:Panel>
<asp:TextBox ID="tbEquipType" runat="server" CssClass="Small floatLeft" />
<ajx:DropDownExtender ID="ex1" runat="server" DynamicServicePath="" 
     DropDownControlID="panelEquipType" TargetControlID="tbEquipType" />
```

My code behind...

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        tbEquipType.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: In which page event are you running this ?

Comment: Page_Load(). I tried to run it in Page_PreRender() and Page_UnLoad() as well, but still no go.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using client side script for setting focus

```
$(function(){
    $('#<%= tbEquipType.ClientID %>').focus();
});
```

if you are using update panel

```
function pageLoad(){
    $('#<%= tbEquipType.ClientID %>').focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The asp.net focus method will not work when AJAX is enabled. Instead use JQuery to easily set the focus on a textbox.

```
function document_ready() {
    $(".MyTextBoxStyle").focus();
}
```

Or like this:

```
function document_ready() {
    $("<%= tbEquipType.ClientID %>").focus();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe I figured it out. I am now calling the focus() method from the (window).load function, and it seems to work like a champ.

```
$(window).load(function () {
        $("#<%=tbEquipType.ClientID%>").focus();
    });
```

Thanks for the assistance!